# Behavior of overriding __gt__ in python

Tags: python

This might sound like a weird question and and most likely has no practical relevance but that said, I came around a (to me) strange behavior in python.

If I have a simple class that overrides the `__gt__` method like this

```py
class K:
    def __init__(self, names):
        if isinstance(names, list):
            self.names = names
        else:
            self.names = [names]

    def __gt__(self, other):
        assert isinstance(other, K)
        return K(self.names + other.names)
```

then I was thinking the following

```py
 print((K("a") > K("b") > K("c")).names)
```

should result n

```py
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

but instead I get

```py
['b', 'c']
```

if I do

```py
print(((K("a") > K("b")) > K("c")).names)
```

it works but without the additional brackets the first statement seems to have disappeared somehow.
There is certainly something about the `__gt__` method I do not quite understand correctly, can you pleas explain what I'm missing and why this is not working in the way I suspected.

Comment: Chained comparisons have a special behavior in Python - it's what allows you to do things like `0 < X < 100`.  Your expression is equivalent to `(K("a") > K("b")) and (K("b") > K("c"))` (except that the middle sub-expression doesn't actually get evaluated twice).

Comment: If you want some sort of concatenation behavior, I would recommend using `__rshift__` to override `>>` instead.

Comment: ok, yes thx to you all that answers my question!